# Python Package: How to handle reference files used in package that are frequently updated by third party

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

## Situation

I am writing a python package to check whether data comply with a certain standard. The standard is provided by a third party and frequently updated. The standard is available as several json files. The package itself should be installed in multi-user HPC environments as well as on local single-user systems. The python package should not be updated too frequently (particularly not updated just to update the json files for the standard) due to its usage in the HPC environment. I do not want to download the json files on each call of the package.

## Current implementation

Originally, I planned to ship the json standard files with the package (subfolder of package installation directory; license of third-party allows this) and update them on the call of the program when the files are older than X days. During development installations, the updating process worked well. However, when installed productively, the package does not seem to have writing permissions in its own installation folder. This is probably a security feature.

## Question

Is it possible to gain writing permissions for specific subfolders of the package's installation directory? If not, is there a best practice how to deals with this situation (e.g. downloading the files in the user's home directory)? I don't want to newly download the files on each program call.

Comment: So the data should always comply with the latest version of the standard? Are users not allowed to check their data against an older version, in case they have no need to upgrade? For determining the appropriate cache directory you might find the [appdirs package](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) helpful.

Comment: @a_guest Thanks for the comment. The appdirs package looks promising. The most recent version of the standard should be used if the user does not provide any version information explicitely. Users may also set an environment variable pointing to the location of a specific version of the standard.

Comment: @a_guest: Is there a major difference between the [xdg](https://pypi.org/project/xdg/) and the appdirs package?

Comment: Using a local file system cache is possible, including versioning, however race conditions can occur if multiple processes use it at the same time (HPC cluster with shared file system). If you have control over the system (you seem since missing write permissions indicate system-wide installation), I'd suggest installing a separate application that mirrors the third party resources and handles the cache (e.g. local webserver; could be bundled as debian package). For private installation this is surely cumbersome, so maybe an install option provides a solution.

Comment: @a_guest : If you have time to write an answer based on your comments I would be happy to accept it.